# What does it mean _NSCFSet?

Tags: ios, swift, nsset

When i debug i get a variable that contain an _NSCFSet value.
I have not found an accurate documentation about the value **_NSCFSet**.

Who can explain to me the meaning of this value ? 
I think that it's similar to the NSSet value, right ?

Thank you all, Good work!

Answer (score 3):

It is private class behind the `NSSet`. `NSSet` uses it internally. Generally in Cocoa when something has underscore before its name it is private.